# Java Reflection, why are the supertype type arguments preserved at runtime

Tags: java, generics

So java has type erasure, which deletes the type arguments (no generic types at runtime). Can someone explain why the supertype type arguments are preserved then?

```
class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {
    public Type getType() {

        Type[] typeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
        return typeArguments[0];
    }
}
```

**What this means basically is**:

```
new ArrayList<String>()// I cannot use reflection to find out the generified type String
```

but

```
new StringList()//I can use reflection to see the generic type String
```

So type erasure is for backwards compatibility, but why are the supertype type arguments preserved then? Is the metadata updated to support it?

Why the one and not the other?

Comment: If you compile code using this class, the `javac` needs to have this information.

Comment: Why would it need the type info for the super class and not the actual class?

Comment: A `StringList` must be an `ArrayList<String>`  however not all `ArrayList` are the same generic type.

Comment: It needs that as it has to make concrete types in the derived class when it specifies them. the fields and methods of the supertype become concrete fields and methods of the child. But its interesting to know that reflection offers it!

Answer (score 7):

It's done for compile time type safety. If the super class of `StringList` was erased to `ArrayList`, there would be no way to protect against

```
StringList stringList = new StringList();
stringList.add(new Integer(123456));
```

If the type remains in the `.class` file for `StringList`, the compiler can correctly refuse the source code above since `new Integer(123456)` is not of type `String` expected by `ArrayList<String>#add(String)`.

Comment: But the java guys decided to use type erasure. Why would this protection work if I have a generified supertype, and the same protection wouldn't work for a simple ArrayList<String>. It makes no sense.

Comment: @mist Please clarify what you mean for _a simple `ArrayList<String>`. If you mean for a local variable, there's no point for the generic type to remain in the byte code. Only the compiler needs it at compilation time. After that piece of code is compiled (successfully), no other checks need to be done against the generic type.

Comment: Interesting. Is that the trick used by Jackson's `TypeReference` and Gson's `TypeToken`? IIRC, Guice also has such a class

Comment: @fge Yes, type tokens. I believe they were first presented [here](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if I have an ArrayList<String>, I don't have a runtime protection against adding an Integer for example.

Comment: @mist Again, explain _where_ you have an `ArrayList<String>`. Where are you trying to add an `Integer` to it? Edit your question with these details.

Comment: A matter of terminology: *byte code* is the instruction set of the Java Virtual Machine, wherein type arguments do not exist. You probably meant to say that type arguments are present in the *class file*. (Ordinarily I would not mind the loose language, but it is precisely the distinction between the instruction set and declarations that gives rise to the different treatment of type arguments OP asks about)

Comment: @meriton I am referring to the bytecode as generated by the compiler and stored in the class file. That bytecode will contain the parameterization of the superclass of `StringList` in its class signature. What am I getting wrong on the terminology side?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, check the answer by omerkudat. There is no runtime protection.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: As I said, byte code is the instruction set of the JVM. That is, the instructions to be executed by a method are specified in byte code in the class file. The method signature, however, is not an instruction, and therefore not expressed in byte code. Put differently, the class file contains byte code, but also declarations, debugging information, information for speedy class file verification, and quite a few other supporting structures. Type arguments are present in the class file, most notably in declarations, but *not* in byte code.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a satisfactory answer to this question, but here is my take on it. Your StringList class is a new type, a subclass of ArrayList. The compiler generates a class file for this new type and adds whatever information is available at compile-time. However, `new ArrayList<String>()` does not generate a new type. This is because you are simply instantiating an existing generic type, and there is no place to store the parameter type of your instance.

The additional data you are seeing is stored in the [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9) attribute of your StringList class. You can see it by opening the .class file in any editor.

Your class is still type-erased, and you have no runtime protection:

```
StringList sl = new StringList();
List l = sl;
l.add(new Integer(123)); // no compile or runtime error
```

A better answer might include how this additional information could be used (by the application or the JVM.)

Comment: Yes, there is no protection. I tried that too. But you can create your own protection using reflection. But for `ArrayList<String>` you can't.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, it is important to distinguish between compile time types (as declared in the source code) and runtime types of individual objects.

Compile time types are used for compiling and linking (in Java, linking occurs when a class file is loaded by the JVM). As you can compile (and link against) class files, compile time types must be retained in their entirety in class files.

Runtime types are used for type checks at runtime, as in cast or `instanceof` instructions. They can also be queried with `object.getClass()`. Erasure means that type arguments are not present in runtime types, i.e. the JVM does not keep track of what type arguments an object was created with:

```
new ArrayList<String>().getClass() == new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass()
```

That is, type arguments are present (and can be queried) in compile time types, but not in runtime types.

Comment: I think the main reason why compile time types must be retained in their entirety in class files, is because classes can be compiled separately in Java. For example, you could be building your classes using a library that someone else has already compiled; you don't have their source; but you must still known all of the method and field declaration types. For example, when compile your program that uses ArrayList, you don't have ArrayList's source. In C++, the declarations would be in a "header". In Java, the "header" and "implementation" are both in the same file, the class file.

Comment: @meriton, there is runtime information for superclass's types, but not for the actual class's types. Why? I don't know where this info is retained, probably some metadata, but you can access it. It is not enforced though.

Comment: You can query compile time types (a.k.a. declared types, because they appear in declarations such as the class declaration in your question) at runtime, and they contain type arguments. The runtime type of an *object*, however, does not.

Comment: Or put differently, source code elements such as classes, methods, or fields have type arguments. Objects do not.

Answer (score 2):

Basically type definitions capture type arguments. Ex:

```
class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {}
```

Since `<String>` is part of the definition of `StringList` here, it is recoverable at runtime. Alternatively, when merely declaring a `new ArrayList<String>` the `<String>` argument is not recoverable.

Comment: And the essence of my question is why is there the one and not the other :)

Comment: Because it would have introduced backwards incompatible changes to Java bytecode. Erasure prevented that.